# How can I install MaaS 1.7.x to 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, maas

I'm going back to 14.04 after running into issues with the vivid release.  In vivid, I was able to select a 1.7 release of MaaS which allowed me to use the Debian installer.   I don't seem to have the right magic to make that happen in 14.04/trusty.   'apt-cache policy maas' gives me:

```
maas:
  Installed: 1.5.4+bzr2294-0ubuntu1.3
  Candidate: 1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2~trusty1
  Version table:
     1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas-maintainers/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
 *** 1.5.4+bzr2294-0ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.4+bzr2294-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     1.5+bzr2252-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

with no option to select a 1.7 variant.  At one point I was runing 1.7 on trusty so it was out there.   I've tried adding repositories: ppa:maas-maintainers/testing and ppa:maas-maintainers/daily-qa-ok without any change.   I'm sure this is a basic question but I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but after looking around I found some ppas for MaaS [here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=maas)

Thanks to Andres Martinez, who posted a set of 1.7.6 packages, you can access them for `apt-get install` after:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andreserl/maas
sudo apt-get update
```